# Adding comments through VBA in Word includes page number field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a procedure that adds a comment balloon into my Word document, but I have noticed that it also adds a page number field (evident by selecting the comment balloon and selecting update field from the context menu).  This only happens when the comment is added through VBA, not when I create comments manually. Is there a way that I can inhibit the page number from being added to the comment?

Code extract below:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Approvals"
    .Forward = True
    .Execute

    If .Found = True Then
        Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="My comment text"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: to be honest I was surprised with your question but then I have realised that I have the same problem ;) Searching google I've found some ideas which just search  `page fields` in comments to remove them. I think this is the way you should go. I didn't find any option to add comment (with VBA) and avoid automatically added page number, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used to delete those page fields. After running the bulk of the code, just before `End Sub` I insert the following:

```
For Each f In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdCommentsStory).Fields
    If f.Type = wdFieldPage Then
        f.Delete
    End If
Next
```

It may not be pretty, but it does the job. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to filter based on, say, comment author.

```
For Each c In ActiveDocument.Comments
   If c.Author = "Macro Name" Then 'Assuming you set it when you created the comment
        Debug.Print c.Range.Fields.Count 'This prints a 0
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you set field codes in comments, this is a bit more selective in what it deletes.  This is designed to run just after you add a particular comment.  However, you can combine something similar with the above to work on all comments.

```
If comment.range.fields.count > 0 Then
    If comment.range.fields.Item(1).Type = wdFieldPage Then
        comment.range.fields.Item(1).Delete
    End If
End If
```